# How to switch size using one function

Tags: javascript, html

My learning of JavaScript is full of pitfalls and I don't really understand the logic of my exo. `I want to use document.querySelectorAll` to change the size of my rectangles to "large" with the same function I used before (`function reDisplay() { ... }`) with a variable let `rectsAreBig = true`.

I have to use a variable that will represent the "current state of the page".
To do this I must use custom variables (which I will use to represent the "state" of the rectangles):
I need to call the function `reDisplay()`;

My style is

```css
.rect {
    background: red;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
}

.rect.blue {
    background: blue;
}

.rect.yellow {
    background: yellow;
}

.rect.green {
    background: green;
}

.smallRect {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

HTML:

```html
 <div class="rectContainer">
            <div id="rect1" class="rect red">
                
            </div>
            <div id="rect2" class="rect red">
                
            </div>
            <div id="rect3" class="rect red"></div>
        </div>
```

My first rectangle should change colour with `document.querySelector` and my code is this and it works even if I am not sure if I do follow the recommendations.

```js
let stateRect1Color = "blue";

let rectsAreBig = true;


let rectContainer = document.querySelector(".rect"); 
console.log(rectContainer);

rectContainer.addEventListener("click", function reDisplay() {
    for (let couleurs = 0; couleurs < 5; couleurs++) {
        console.log(couleurs);
        let lePremierRectangle = document.querySelector("#rect1"); 
        switch (stateRect1Color) {
            case "blue": 
                stateRect1Color = "red"; 
                // document
                //     .querySelector("#rect1")
                lePremierRectangle.classList.remove("blue"); 
                // document
                //     .querySelector("#rect1")
                lePremierRectangle.classList.add("red"); 
                break;
            case "red":
                stateRect1Color = "yellow"; 
                // document
                //     .querySelector("#rect1")
                lePremierRectangle.classList.remove("red"); 
                // document
                //     .querySelector("#rect1")
                lePremierRectangle.classList.add("yellow");
                break;
            case "yellow": 
                stateRect1Color = "green";
                // document
                //     .querySelector("#rect1")
                lePremierRectangle.classList.remove("yellow"); 
                // document
                //     .querySelector("#rect1")
                lePremierRectangle.classList.add("green"); 
                break;
            case "green":
                stateRect1Color = "blue"; 
                // document
                //     .querySelector("#rect1")
                lePremierRectangle.classList.remove("green"); 
                // document
                //     .querySelector("#rect1")
                lePremierRectangle.classList.add("blue");
                break;
            default:
                console.log();
        }

        console.log(stateRect1Color); 
    }
```

and my second rectangle code doesn't work to change the shape

```js
let rectContainer2 = document.querySelectorAll(".rect"); 

rectContainer2.addEventListener("click", function reDisplay() {
    
    let leDeuxiemeRectangle = document.querySelector("#rect2"); 

    

    for (let i = 0; i < TousLesRectangles.length; i++) {
        
        if (rectsAreBig == true) {
            console.log((rectsAreBig = true)); 
            
            rectsAreBig = false; /
            // On récupère le rectangle 2
            leDeuxiemeRectangle.classList.remove(".smallRect");
            console.log(smallRect); 

            leDeuxiemeRectangle.classList.add(".smallRect"); 
            console.log(); // On affiche la valeur de la variable rectsAreBig dans la console
        } else {
            rectsAreBig = true;

            leDeuxiemeRectangle.classList.remove(".smallRect"); 

            leDeuxiemeRectangle.classList.add(".smallRect"); 
            console.log();rectsAreBig dans la console
        }
        console.log(rectsAreBig);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, could i ask you why it return this error Uncaught TypeError: rectContainer2.addEventListener is not a function ?

Answer (score 0):

What if you made it like an singleton (=object literal) handler object (or some other object/class structure).

I'll give my 2 cents. Here is a quick plain js example (could be much better):

First set the clicks to bind into the handler method on init/pageload etc. It has also the rectsAreBig in memory. So if you call "rectChanger.rectsAreBig = false" and click the rectangles after that, it should then change the clicked rectangle to smallRect-class and change the color (i copy pasted your code there with minor change that it wont break). We simply pass the element from the click to the handler and it refreshes the class values on each click.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.rect').forEach(
(el) => el.addEventListener('click', (event)=> 
rectChanger.changeColorAndSize(event.target)));

var rectChanger = {
rectsAreBig: true,
rectClassName: "rect",
rectSizes: {
    large: "normalRect",
    small: "smallRect"
},
rectColorClasses: ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow"],

changeColorAndSize: function(elementClicked){
        this.changeSize(elementClicked);
        this.changeColor(elementClicked);
},

changeColor: function(elementClicked){
    var color = this.rectColorClasses.filter((color) => {
        if(elementClicked.classList.contains(color)){
            return color;
        }
    });
    console.log(color);
    if(color.length > 0){

    switch (color[0]) {
        case "blue": 
            elementClicked.classList.remove("blue"); 
            elementClicked.classList.add("red"); 
            break;
        case "red":
            elementClicked.classList.remove("red"); 
            elementClicked.classList.add("yellow");
            break;
        case "yellow": 
            elementClicked.classList.remove("yellow"); 
            elementClicked.classList.add("green"); 
            break;
        case "green":
            elementClicked.classList.remove("green"); 
            elementClicked.classList.add("blue");
            break;
        default:
            console.log('no color found' + elementClicked.id);
    }
  }
},
changeSize: function(elementClicked){
    if(this.rectsAreBig){
        elementClicked.classList.add(this.rectSizes.large);
        elementClicked.classList.remove(this.rectSizes.small);
    }
    else {
        elementClicked.classList.add(this.rectSizes.large);
        elementClicked.classList.remove(this.rectSizes.small);
    }
}
}
```